# Excel date & Time in 24 H instead of AM/PM

Tags: microsoft-excel, time, date

I have tried many different tips and tricks to have the below date converted to 24H format in Excel 2016 with no luck. It seems to not be identified as date & time at all. Some things I tried:

1. When importing from CSV, marking column as date and time
2. Importing as is (from Aternity web page) and marking as date, time custom (`mm-dd-yyyy TT:MM:SS`)
3. Using Transpose (import has times in rows and not in columns) and splitting date from time, then marking them as such.

Nothing seems to work. Format: 6/13/2019 1:45:00 PM

It is clear to me the export from Aternity is flawed as all date and time up to 06-12-2019  23:55:00 has one format, and another from 6/13/2019 12:00:00 AM which makes my graphs and pivot 'messy'.

Comment: When importing, you need to also tell Excel the format of the column in the CSV file with regard to is it `MDY` or `DMY`

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

For a `CSV` file:

**Data tab -->** `Get&Transform Data` **-->** `From Text/CSV`

When the file opens, you are probably using Comma` as the delimiter.  This will leave the Date/Time column together as a single column.

`Transform Data`

Right click on the date column and choose `Change Type --> From Locale` from the drop down menu.

Set the Data Type to Date/Time

Then choose the locale that matches the format in the CSV file (eg: English-Europe or English-United States.

[image]

Then `OK` and `Close and Load` and you should be converted properly.